# Encontrar y reemplazar varias palabras dentro de un string en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Muy buenos días a todos. Actualmente estoy trabajando en un código en python que me permita encontrar ciertas palabras y concatenarlas con otro mensaje. Pero lo único que logro es que me reemplace la palabra que deseo las mismas veces en el resto de similitudes. Es decir:

Tengo el siguiente string:

```py
complement = "Hola, saludos a TATA-12 y TATA-23 en este texto."
```

Y deseo concatenar todas las palabras que tengan mayúscula sostenida mas un guion y finalicen con numero, pero lo que logro es lo siguiente:

```
Hola, saludos a TATA-12 En casa y TATA-12 En casa en este texto.
Hola, saludos a TATA-23 En casa y TATA-23 En casa en este texto.
Hola, saludos a TATA-12 En casa y TATA-12 En casa en este texto.
Hola, saludos a TATA-23 En casa y TATA-23 En casa en este texto.
Hola, saludos a TATA-12 En casa y TATA-12 En casa en este texto.
Hola, saludos a TATA-23 En casa y TATA-23 En casa en este texto.
```

Y lo que deseo es:

```
Hola, saludos a TATA-12 En casa y TATA-23 En casa en este texto.
```

Mi código es es siguiente:

```py
def find_replace():
    complement = "Hola, saludos a TATA-12 y TATA-23 en este texto."
    to_list = re.findall(r'[A-Z]*[\W-][\d]+', complement)
    add = "En casa"

    for item in to_list:
        print(re.sub(r'[A-Z]*[\W-][\d]+', item + " " + add, complement))
```

He consultado en otros lugares, pero aun no logro encontrar una solución. Me gustaría saber si alguno de ustedes me puede colaborar al respecto. Se lo agradecería inmensamente. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar grupos de captura.

Un grupo de captura es una parte de una expresión regular que encierras entre paréntesis. Esto hace que `re.sub()`, cuando encuentre algo que encaje con esa expresión regular, lo guarde en una variable (no una variable python, sino una variable interna de  la expresión regular).

Estas variables tienen un nombre especial, que son `\1` para el primer grupo de captura (el primer grupo de paréntesis en la expresión regular), `\2` para el segundo, etc... Puedes usar esas variables como parte de la cadena que pasas a `re.sub()` como segundo parámetro.

Por ejemplo, si quieres poner entre guiones bajos todos los números que encuentres harías:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"(\d+)", r"_\1_", "Esto es 12 una 234 prueba")
'Esto es _12_ una _234_ prueba'
```

Como ves, la expresión `\d+` que encaja con secuencias de números la he puesto entre paréntesis. Eso la convierte en un grupo de captura. En el texto de sustitución he usado `\1` para representar "lo que haya encajado con el grupo de captura". Como ves en el resultado, cada vez que hay un encaje en la cadena de entrada, se captura ese encaje en el grupo 1, y luego en el resultado aparece sustituido por ese mismo, pero entre guiones bajos.

No es difícil entonces adaptar esto a tu caso:

```
def find_replace():
    complement = "Hola, saludos a TATA-12 y TATA-23 en este texto."
    add = "En casa"
    print(re.sub(r'([A-Z]*[\W-][\d]+)', r'\1 '+add, complement))
```

Comment: Hola abulafia, entiendo lo que me quieres decir pero, en caso de que yo no sepa que string voy a recibir y con que palabras en especifico ¿Se podría adaptar igual?

Comment: No te entiendo.. pero el mismo `re.sub()` que puse al final te vale para cualquier texto que esté en `complement` (podrías recibirlo como parámetro) y lo que hará será cambiar cada trozo que encaje con el patrón `[A-Z]*[\W-][\d]+` por ese mismo trozo más el texto contenido en `add`

Comment: Acabo de observar no obstante que quizás la expresión regular que usas no haga lo que quieres, pues también te encajaría cadenas como "TATA&12" o "TATA 23". En realidad, admite cualquier cosa entre las MAYUSCULAS y el numero, salvo el guión bajo ("TATA_12" no encajaría) ¿Seguro que es eso lo que querías?

Comment: Hola una vez mas, comprendo lo que me quieres decir, y también modificare la expresión regular, ya que lo que mencionas es totalmente cierto. Muchas gracias nuevamente.